# Getting collection of mixed types from single table inheritance with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following:

```rb
class JiraIssue < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Incident < JiraIssue
end
```

Later in my code, I want to call `JiraIssue.all` and get a mixed bag of `Incident` and `JiraIssue` instances. But the way it's written now, I can only get back one type (or the other).

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can "static cast" your subset of incident from `JiraIssue` to `Incident` class by using `becomes` (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes).

The code would look something like this:

```
jira_issue # type: JiraIssue

if jira_issue.isIncident?
   return jira_issue.becomes(Incident)
end
```